# Browser tab shows project name while Flutter Web app loading

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm creating a Flutter Web app. When it is starting up and downloading the Flutter content the tab in the browser displays the project name instead of the app name. This looks ugly.

[image]

My project name is `com.example.my_app_client`, but my app name is **My App**.

How do I change the browser tab text to show "My App"?

*I found the answer and I am adding it below as a Q&A style self answer.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a top level folder called **web** inside your project. Open the **index.html** file in that folder and you should see something similar to the following:

*web/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>my_app_client</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the title text to your app name:

```
<title>My App</title>
```

This will then show the correct title while the Flutter app is loading.

[image]

Comment: This answer is only partially correct: The HTML title tag value is overridden by `MateralApp` :
`onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle,`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `title` property on the `MaterialApp` widget, this is what worked for me

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title:'Your Title',
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: appTheme(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is a good place to set your title, it won't show until the app loads, which is what this problem is about.  See the Suragch 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> If you want it to show **while loading the screen** use the
> `index.html` method as answered before by [Suragch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch)
>
> If you want it to show **after the screen loads** use the `Material App` method as answered by [6thsage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7715345/6thsage)

If you want both, just use both

**Below is the while loading screen method explained**

There is a top level folder called web inside your project. Open the index.html file in that folder and you should see something similar to the following:

web/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>my_app_client</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript">. 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the title text to your app name:

**Below is the after-loading screen method explained**

My App
This will then show the correct title while the Flutter app is loading.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title:'Your Title',
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: appTheme(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `web/manifest.json` file.

```
{
    "name": "<App name>",
    "short_name": "<App short name>",
    "description": "<Your app description>",
    // something else
}
```

after this build the app again and open it in incognito tab or clear browsing data